# Harmonic spinors on closed hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, differential-operators, spin-geometry

Does anyone know an example of a closed spin hyperbolic manifold of dimension 3 or greater such that the kernel of the Dirac operator is non-trivial?

I'm mainly interested in the 3-dimensional case but would be happy to hear about higher dimensions as well.  Note that Hitchin showed that for a particular choice of spin structure on a surface, the Dirac operator necessarily has kernel. There are strong results of Bär (The Dirac Operator on Hyperbolic Manifolds of Finite Volume, J. Diff. Geom. 54 (2000), 439--488) for finite-volume hyperbolic manifolds but I haven't found anything for closed hyperbolic manifolds.

Comment: By the way, in an earlier paper of Baer, he shows that every 3-manifold has a metric which has harmonic spinors. Of course, it is not clear that the hyperbolic metric is it...

Comment: On any even-dimensional spin manifold with non-vanishing $\hat{A}$-genus, there exist harmonic spinors, due to Atiyah-Singer, whatever metric you choose. Now you just need to find a negatively curved spin manifold with non-vanishing $\hat{A}$-genus...

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig As far as I recall Pontrjagin classes of a hyperbolic manifold are trivial in real cohomology, using Chern-Weil theory. (I don't have a handy reference, but compare Igor Belgradek's comments in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107716/are-negatively-pinched-manifold-locally-conformally-flat). This implies that the A-hat class is zero, so the index of the Dirac operator is 0. That's kind of the point of the question, to find examples where the kernel is non-zero in a setting where the A-S index theorem doesn't help.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: I spent a couple of minutes looking for a reference, and found that it comes from Chern's paper, On Curvature and Characteristic Classes of a Riemann Manifold. Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg
October 1955, Volume 20, Issue 1-2, pp 117-126.  Of course, this predates the Dirac operator and the index theorem, but the characteristic class computation is there.

Comment: I know nothing about harmonic spinors, but my suggestion is to talk to people who study automorphic forms. There is a neat trick (using theta-series and congruence subgroups) for constructing compact hyperbolic manifolds supporting nonvanishing automorphic forms of certain kind, which may work in your setting. I learned this trick from Gordan Savin years ago, see Proposition on page 204 of his paper "Cusp forms", Israel Math Journal, 1992. You have to get lucky for this trick to work with harmonic spinors since it requires absolute convergence, but it's worth asking.

Comment: Hi Danny, I just noticed this question of yours now... a year late.  Do you have a guess as to which way the answer might go, or is this pretty much a wide-open question?

Comment: I have a feeling that you can construct examples, and even an idea for a construction. I tried to get a student to follow up on this plan, but, well, kids these days... I'd be happy to share my idea off-line if you're interested.  I also think that the suggestion from @Misha is a good one. In any event the question is still open.

Comment: Danny: My suggestion is to outsource this question not to your student but to somebody in automorphic forms. There should be plenty of these guys in the greater Boston area.

Comment: Misha: Thanks. We have a visitor next year who does automorphic forms, and I am hoping to take this up with him. I was referring to a more topological approach of mine, which I tried to get a student interested in.

Comment: I guess one has examples of harmonic spinors when the index theorem does not demand it in high dimension as a result of [Crowley-Schick-Steimle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04660). Of course, still nothing in dimensions 3 or 4, or examples that are actually hyperbolic.

Comment: The result you attribute to Hitchin is due to [Atiyah](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1971_4_4_1_47_0) (or Riemann). . . He systematically studies how the parity the changes as the spin structure changes. Do you know what happens with 9- or 10-dimensional hyperbolic manifolds? Do they have uniformly even parity?

Comment: Thanks; I stand corrected. (Hitchin's paper, of course, attributes this to Atiyah, so I should have known better.) Your second question sounds hard; it seems that you're asking about whether certain elements in the spin cobordism group can be represented by hyperbolic manifolds.

Comment: I now have examples (with Ratcliffe and Tschantz) in dimension 4; I will put some details in an answer below.

Comment: Hello,Professor Danny , since this question was active here 1 year ago I am asking here for three dimension agin. Are there any updates for closed hyperbolic three manifolds having trivial or non trivial harmonic spinor?

Comment: @GorapadaBera Recently, McKee Krumpak and I found examples of closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds with harmonic spinors. A paper is in preparation.  I don't know examples where it is shown that the kernel of the Dirac operator is trivial.

Answer (score 12):

I'm happy to be able to answer my own question! John Ratcliffe, Steven Tschantz and I showed that the Dirac operator on the [Davis manifold](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-093-02/S0002-9939-1985-0770546-7/S0002-9939-1985-0770546-7.pdf) (a closed hyperbolic 4-manifold constructed by Mike Davis) has non-zero kernel. This is in the preprint [Harmonic spinors on the Davis hyperbolic 4-manifold](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06382) that we posted on the arxiv today.

The method is to find a symmetry of the manifold that respects a particular spin structure, and use the G-spin theorem to show that the G-spinor index is non-zero. This can only happen if the kernel of the Dirac operator is non-zero. The method also works in dimension 2 (where the result is of course not new) and in principle in any even dimension. It doesn't (to my knowledge) work in odd dimensions, although Misha's suggestions in the comments above seem promising there.

Comment: Is the Davis manifold another non-trivial contractible manifold but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, like the Whitehead manifold? I feel kind of amazed.

Comment: @Bombyxmori No, it  is nothing like the Whitehead manifold - look at the link in Danny's answeer.

Comment: @IgorRivin: I see. I was told by Tam it is something similar.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: Same Davis, different manifold. The ones you are thinking of are closed aspherical manifolds of dimension $\geq 4$ whose universal covers are not simply connected at $\infty$. Davis, Michael W. Groups generated by reflections and aspherical manifolds not covered by Euclidean space.  Ann. of Math. (2) 117 (1983), no. 2, 293-324.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rula Tabbash in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0104233.pdf), all negatively curved closed manifolds admit harmonic spinors (and no positively curved ones do). I am not 100% certain, since this is a physics paper, and so it is not clear if he is assuming something unstated...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's polite to comment negatively on specific papers, but I feel skeptical of the one you cite. There is no argument for the existence of harmonic spinors in negative curvature, other than the statement of the well-known theorem of Lichnerowicz (the converse of his claim!) that positive scalar curvature obstructs harmonic spinors.  Even for surfaces, the claim that all negatively curved closed manifolds admit harmonic spinors is false, by results of Hitchin and Ammann-Dahl-Humbert.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Yes, precisely. I didn't know about the results you mention, but certainly the "Bochner" obstruction does not seem to show a positive result.